# how to create IisManagerAuth FTP user account in IIS7?

Tags: c#, iis-7

i want to creatre an ftp user acccount using IisManagerAuth
i dont want to create using windows user account. 
what all seetings i have to make in iis for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean programmatically? You should use Microsoft.Web.Management.dll for that and use: [Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthentication.CreateUser(userName, password) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.server.managementauthentication.createuser.aspx)

And to add the permissions for a site, you can use [ManagementAuthorization.Grant( ) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.server.managementauthorization.grant.aspx)

Comment: no. currently i want to do the settings in IIS. later i will do the same programitically.now, i was able to create the users, but   i was not able to login using those accounts

Comment: Please Explain me about this methods i need this type of requirment

Comment: i need to add user with c# code and Diff Diff Users have diff diff username/pwd for ftp access